# wireshark dissector- many locals in lua file

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing a tool that transfers some XML file into a LUA file. The XML file contains above 100 messages.

I have to have as minimum following 2 statements for each message:

```
local p_multi = Proto("multi", "MultiProto");
local f=p_multi.fields
```

meaning that I have at least 200 'local' records which is limited by LUA. I've tried to use it as follows, but getting an error:

```
local locals={}
locals.p_multi = Proto("multi", "MultiProto");
locals.f=p_multi.fields
```

I've also tried to remove the local statement, but in Wireshark I've received an empty message content (i.e all the fields were with null value)

```
p_multi = Proto("multi", "MultiProto");
f=p_multi.fields
```

Any suggestion how to solve it?

Thank you :)

Comment: Replace `locals.f=p_multi.fields` with `locals.f=locals.p_multi.fields`

Comment: Thank you! With some additional changes, based on your clue, it worked for the first issue, but all the fields are with null value.

Comment: now issue solved